# How would i calculate the inner product of two arrays?

Tags: arrays

```
int inner_product(int a[], int b[], int count){

int productsum;
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        productsum=a[i]*b[i
```

I'm trying to find the inner product of two arrays and i'm stuck here. I don't know what to do next. I don't think i'm doing it right...

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: Right now you are only calculating the product of two array elements, and then overwrite that result in the next loop iteration. If you want to add those products up … well then _do so_ …

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialise the result, and you didn't accumulate inside the loop. Try something like this:

```
int inner_product(int a[], int b[], int count)
{
    int productsum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        productsum += a[i]*b[i];
    }
    return productsum;
}
```